# Is it possible to construct an x86_64 Opcode which jumps to a SIMD register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, simd, opcode

I had an interesting thought this morning. I wonder if it's possible to construct an unconditional jump to an address stored within a SIMD register such as XMM0. Obviously, it shouldn't be, and I've never seen a compiler do it, but I wonder if it's possible to put together an opcode that does it.

Now what I *do not* mean is say doing some arithmetic in the SIMD register, moving it to a general purpose register, and then doing say

```
JMP EAX
```

What I'd like to do is, is figure out if there is an acceptable X86_64 opcode that will do something like

```
JMP XMM0
```

Of course, somehow you'd have to only grab the first half of the register. This is all likely not possible, but I'm curious if it is or exactly why it *can't* be done.

Comment: No you can't. http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html

Comment: You can't even push those registers to stack so your best bet seems to be moving it to EAX and then JMP EAX.

Comment: I don't know who's downvoting this, it meets the format requirements... Also the question is what can be constructed in the encoding, not what is possible based on the x86 docs.

Answer (score 2):

Such an instruction doesn't exist. The only `jmp` instructions are:

```
EB cb        JMP rel8         jump short
E9 cw/cd     JMP rel16/32     jump near
FF /4        JMP r/m16/32/64  jump near indirect
EA cd/cp     JMP ptr16:16/32  jump far
FF /5        JMP m16:16/32    jump far indirect
REX.W FF /5  JMP m16:64       jump far indirect
```

Each of these instructions either jump to an address given in an immediate, a general purpose register, or a memory operand. No SSE register can be used.

There are a number of other instructions that could be used for jumping such as `ret`, but none of them support jumping to an SSE register either.

Comment: I am curious, can you give ma n example of the jump far indirect for say EAX? I'm not sure what your notation "FF /5" means or "REX.W FF /5" means.

Comment: @baordog `FF /5` means “opcode `ff` then a modr/m byte with the second operand having the value 5.”  This 5 is an *extended opcode* encoded as a second argument to instructions that usually only take one argument. For example, `JMP FAR [EAX]` encodes as `ff 28` where 28 (in octal, 050) is the modr/m byte encoding the operand `[EAX]` (represented by octal 0x0) and the extended opcode 5.

Comment: REX.W means “A REX prefix with the W bit turned on.” REX prefixes are 40 to 4F, the W bit has the value 8, so REX.W alone is 48. The REX.W bit changes the operand size from 32 bit to 64 bit. For example, the instruction `jmp far [rax]` jumping to a 64 bit address is encoded as `48 ff 28`.

Answer (score 2):

Although it does go through memory and it is technically 3 instructions but you could argue that `48 8D 64 24 F8 66 0F D6 04 24 C3` is effectively a `jmp xmm0` opcode.
Of course it is just

```
lea rsp, [rsp-8]
movq [rsp], xmm0
ret
```

which might fall under your exclusion, but it doesn't clobber any registers or flags so in case that was your reason, this should work.

If you have the red zone available, you can do

```
movq [rsp-8], xmm0
jmp [rsp-8]
```

instead.

Comment: Keep in mind the first approach will break the `call`/`ret` predictor, probably incurring a mispredict and possibly several more on subsequent `ret` instructions.